# react-scroll navigate and scroll to anchor from any page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-scroll

I'm using [react-scroll](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll) to scroll from the Nav to any preset anchor element.
I chose it because it also provides an `active` class to the Nav items when element is in viewport.

This exmple works if i'm on the HomePage. But if i click the navbar item from another page it doesn't work.

I need to make the scrolling work from another page as well.

Need to mention that **all the Anchor Elements are on the HomePage** and using `create-react-app` with `v5 router`.

[CODESANDBOX example](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-link-example-forked-tk54l?file=/src/Home.js)
[Github issue link](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll/issues/445)

PS: If you know any better library that can do this and add `active` class please post it here.

```
import { Element} from 'react-scroll';

export function HomePage() {
    return (
        <>
                <title>Home</title>
                <Banner />

                <Element name="price-plan-list">
                    <PriceplanList />
                </Element>

                <Element name="entertainment-area">
                    <EntertainmentArea />
                </Element>
        </>
    );
}
```

And this is the NavbarItem:

```
import { Link as AnchorLink } from 'react-scroll';

        <NavItem key={index}>
            <AnchorLink
                activeClass="active"
                to={item.link}
                spy={true}
                hashSpy={true}
                duration={1000}
            >
                {item.title}
            </AnchorLink>
        </NavItem>
```